# Inserting into a database for a selected combobox and datagridview values in Windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2008, combobox

So I'm developing this Windows form application such that it displays details that are chosen based on selected combobox value. Now what I want to do is for the selected combobox value, I should be able to add more details through the datagridview and make the update in the database. However I'm not able to match the combobox value to the datagridview value.

Eg: If I've chosen Transaction ID:1, I should be able to add in a new row in the datagridview and update that into my database along with Transaction ID:1. However only the datagridview values get updated but the transid column in my database stays null. I want it to have the selected combobox value. Could someone please help me out?
Here's my code

```
string cb = comboBox2.Text;                
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();    
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOPPLIJEML\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Trans;Integrated Security=True";
con.Open();
SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products3(TransId)VALUES('" +cb + "')", con);
scom.ExecuteNonQuery();
sAdapter.Update(sTable);
```

Clearly this doesn't work. Basically I want to merge those two lines.

Comment: You can't insert.  It will add a new row and give an error if you are duplicating the Primary Key.  Use "Update" instead of "Insert".  Remember the format of the Update is different from the Insert.

Comment: Transid isn't a primary key in this example. Its actually a foreign key as I have another table. So I should be able to insert.

Comment: If you are trying to merge two lines, then insert twice won't work.

Comment: I know it doesn't that's why I asked for help with that :P Its not my actual code. Its just a way of explaining what I want to do.

Comment: Shouldn't the insert be adding two values instead of one?